# jquery onload select days

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using [this plugin](http://codebits.weebly.com/plugins/category/weekline-day-picker) to select multiple week days from the user. As I can see everything is setup correctly, I can select days, save that data to the db and on editing I can retrieve data back to the ui, but problem is that this data is correctly loaded on edit mode inside ui but it's not selected on week days ui control.

1 picture is saying more that 1000 words :)

on load data (edit mode) this is current situation
[image]

but should be like this
[image]

this input with id `DaysOfWeekSelected` once setup correctly will be hidden by default.

**Knowing all this and having data already inside view how can select this days from index (0,5,6) into plugin?**

Just to mention that all scripts are loaded correctly, plugin works correctly on user selection (change days).

Update:
I tried with some dummy data select days on page load using

```
$("#repeatOnDays").weekLine("setSelected", "0,1,2,3,4");
```

anyone to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#repeatOnDays").weekLine("setSelected", $('#DaysOfWeekSelected').val());
});
```

$('#DaysOfWeekSelected').val() would return "0,5,6", which would then be set through setSelected.

This should work fine assuming that the test you did with the dummy data worked (you never said what the result of your test was).

Here is jsfiddle link I used:

https://jsfiddle.net/uu1uk7ro/

Comment: test with dummy data doesnt work. I will try your solution. back in 5

Comment: See my update with attached jsfiddle to show a working example

Comment: Yeah I think its a jQuery version error. In the fiddle I used the same version they were using on the demo site you linked and if you use a newer version, it breaks.

Comment: ok, I will try in the morning. Anyway thank you. Very helpful.

Comment: does any one knows how to refresh this weekline picker once it's values are submited?